# how to write a title page in LaTeX?

Tags: latex

I'm trying to write that code [title page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLspp.png) in the picture below, Could anyone tell me how to write it?

Comment: Can you make a [mre] that shows us which documentclass and packages you use?

Comment: i do't mind using any package as long as the result will be like shown on the picture

Comment: thank you very much!! can you recommend any books for a beginner?

Comment: Have a look at https://www.learnlatex.org/ or https://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/index.html

Comment: Please add more information to your question. What is "that code"? And is this in any way related to programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach using tikz:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{duckuments}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\fill[blue!20!white] (current page.south east) rectangle (current page.north west);
\draw[thick] ([xshift=1cm,yshift=1cm]current page.south west) rectangle ([xshift=-1cm,yshift=-1cm]current page.north east);
\node[anchor=east,font=\Huge\sffamily] at ([yshift=5cm,xshift=-2cm]current page.east) {Victor Hugo};
\node[anchor=west,font=\Huge\sffamily] at ([yshift=3cm,xshift=2cm]current page.west) {Les miserables};
\draw[thick] ([yshift=4cm,xshift=2cm]current page.west) -- ([yshift=4cm,xshift=-2cm]current page.east);
\node at ([yshift=2cm]current page.south) {some text};
\end{tikzpicture}

\duckument

\end{document}
```

[image]